# StackOverflowError at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.EntityIterableCache.putIfNotCached

Tags: java, xodus

My code is throwing the error below:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.EntityIterableCache.putIfNotCached(EntityIterableCache.java:100)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.EntityIterableBase.asProbablyCached(EntityIterableBase.java:578)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.EntityIterableBase.iterator(EntityIterableBase.java:138)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:72)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:59)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:55)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:23)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.EntityIterableBase.iterator(EntityIterableBase.java:138)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:72)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:59)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:55)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:23)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.EntityIterableBase.iterator(EntityIterableBase.java:138)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:72)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable$SortedIterator.<init>(MinusIterable.java:59)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:55)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.iterate.binop.MinusIterable.getIteratorImpl(MinusIterable.java:23)
```

It does not point exactly where in my code is the root cause, but I know in my code I have this:

```java
EntityIterable tempEntities = txn.findWithProp(entityType, propertyName);
tempEntities.forEach(entity -> {
  if (!match(entity.getProperty(propertyName))) {
    tempEntities = tempEntities.minus(txn.getSingletonIterable(entity));
  } 
);
```

And I know that the count for the `tempEntities` is 10,000+ items, since the code did a save for 10,000+ entities prior to this throwing.

Does it mean you can't iterate over like 10K entities with Xodus?

Comment: Even `setCachingDisabled(true)` is configured it still throws the `StackOverflowError` error

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you can iterate over 10K entities. Don't create iterables via singletons and binary operations (union, intersect, minus). This is API misusage. Even if you provide sufficient stack size for the JVM, performance problems would haunt you.

Comment: What is the proper usage to achieve the same result?

Comment: Populate suitable entites to a List<Entity>.

Comment: Okay, would like to apply that, but conditions in our case is chained, so it it goes out of the `EntityIterable` it won't be part of the other conditions/actions checks anymore, a problem which is so hard to solve indeed